# Adding/Multiplying tensors and vector along a specific axis

Tags: python, numpy, tensorflow

How can the following function be **efficiently** implemented in tensorflow and/or numpy?

```
add_along_axis(tensor=T, vector=v, axis=k)
     # T is a tensor of shape (N1,...,Nd) (unknown beforehand)
     # v is a vector with N components
     # k is an integer such that Nk=N
     S = T+v, summed along k
     return S
```

That is `S` is the `(N1,..,Nd)` tensor with the components `S[i1,...,id]=T[i1,...,id] + v[ik]`

Note that potentially any number of `Nj`, `j≠k` could coincidentally be equal to `N`, so standard broadcasting is not an option.

**Example**: Let `T = np.zeros( (3,3,3) )` and `v = [1,2,3]` then the correct output should be

```
f(T,v,1) = [[[1., 1., 1.],  [[2., 2., 2.],  [[3., 3., 3.],
             [1., 1., 1.],   [2., 2., 2.],   [3., 3., 3.],
             [1., 1., 1.]],  [2., 2., 2.]],  [3., 3., 3.]]] 

f(T,v,2) = [[[1., 1., 1.],  [[1., 1., 1.],  [[1., 1., 1.],
             [2., 2., 2.],   [2., 2., 2.],   [2., 2., 2.],
             [3., 3., 3.]],  [3., 3., 3.]],  [3., 3., 3.]]]

f(T,v,3) = [[[1., 2., 3.],  [[1., 2., 3.],  [[1., 2., 3.],
             [1., 2., 3.],   [1., 2., 3.],   [1., 2., 3.],
             [1., 2., 3.]],  [1., 2., 3.]],  [1., 2., 3.]]]
```

Here, the target behaviour can be achieved by writing `T+v[:,None,None]` , `T+v[None,:,None]` and `T+v[None,None,:]` respectively. However, I do not see how this approach could work  in the case where the tensor shape is not pre-defined.

Comment: can u add a concrete numerical example of what you want to do?

Comment: @UmangGupta I added an example.

Answer (score 0):

You can generate automatically the `v[:,None,None]` for any dimension of T and any axis `k` by doing a list comprehension such as:

```
def f(T,v,k):
    return T+v[[np.newaxis if i+1 != k else slice(None) for i in range(T.ndim) ]]
```

`np.newaxis` is equivalent to `None`, and `slice(None)` is equivalent to `:`. The result is like expected:

```
print (f(T,v,2))
array([[[1., 1., 1.],
        [2., 2., 2.],
        [3., 3., 3.]],

       [[1., 1., 1.],
        [2., 2., 2.],
        [3., 3., 3.]],

       [[1., 1., 1.],
        [2., 2., 2.],
        [3., 3., 3.]]])
```

Comment: `np.newaxis` is not faster, it is actually an [alias](https://docs.scipy.org/doc/numpy/reference/constants.html#numpy.newaxis) for `None`. In other words, `np.newaxis == None`

Answer (score 0):

Just append T.ndim-k unit length dimensions to v and numpy's broadcasting rules work as designed:

```
def f(T, v, k):
    v = asarray(v)
    return T + v.reshape(v.shape + (1,)*(T.ndim-k))
```

Note that your definition of k is one greater than the standard numpy axis numbering; you might consider reducing k by 1 and calling it "axis".